# Two-columns figure at current page (below other figure)

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column, subcaption

I'm wondering if it is possible to show a two column figure in a page where another figure has already been displayed. In other words, I didn't want to spawn the two column figure to a new page.

I tried that:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Fig A1}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\subcaptionbox{Fig A2}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\subcaptionbox{Fig A2}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\caption{Figure A}  
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Fig B1}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\subcaptionbox{Fig B2}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\subcaptionbox{Fig B2}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\caption{Figure B}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure*}[!b]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Fig C1}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\subcaptionbox{Fig C2}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\subcaptionbox{Fig C2}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\caption{Figure C}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

I would like to have them in one single page, since they fit together.

Thank you.

Comment: Your floats are to big to be placed on one page. According to (La)TeX rules, the float, exception is [p] option, can occupy a fraction of page. This can be changed, but why you not put all pictures in one float? i this case all will be keep together. In one float you can use more captions, if this is matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[p]
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Fig A1}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\subcaptionbox{Fig A2}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\subcaptionbox{Fig A2}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\caption{Figure A}  

\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Fig B1}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\subcaptionbox{Fig B2}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\subcaptionbox{Fig B2}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\caption{Figure B}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip


\subcaptionbox{Fig C1}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\subcaptionbox{Fig C2}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\subcaptionbox{Fig C2}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{teste}} \hfill
\caption{Figure C}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```